# iPhone 7+ invalid passcode and iTunes restore fails on incompatible firmware file

Tags: iphone, itunes, firmware

I have an iPhone 7 Plus, which has been reset to the factory defaults. After that, I normally went through the onboarding process, configured everything and set up screen passcode. After initialization had completed, I wanted to unlock the phone with the passcode but it kept saying the passcode was invalid, even though I'm 100% it was correct.
Therefore, my phone got blocked and so I wanted to connect it to iTunes and restore it.
iTunes downloaded the latest OS update (`iPhone_5.5_P3_14.7.1_18G82_Restore.ipsw`) but when trying to install it shows an error saying

[image]

Any ideas? I'm using MacOS Mojave

Comment: Please don't put answers at the end of the question; that's what the answer space is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by downloading [AnyFix](https://www.imobie.com/anyfix/ios-system-recovery.htm). It's quite sad that you cannot resolve it with the official iTunes software and must pay for 3rd party services but on the other hand big kudos to iMobie.